# Savings Account Class + How to turn in?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

The problem
Design a SavingsAccount class that stores a savings account’s annual interest rate and balance. The class constructor should accept the amount of the savings account’s starting balance. The class should also have methods for subtracting the amount of a withdrawal, adding the amount of a deposit, and adding the amount of monthly interest to the balance. The monthly interest rate is the annual interest rate divided by twelve. To add the monthly interest to the balance, multiply the monthly interest rate by the balance, and add the result to the balance.

Test the class in a program that calculates the balance of a savings account at the end of a period of time. It should ask the user for the annual interest rate, the starting balance, and the number of months that have passed since the account was established. A loop should then iterate once for every month, performing the following:

Ask the user for the amount deposited into the account during the month. Use the class method to add this amount to the account balance.
Ask the user for the amount withdrawn from the account during the month. Use the class method to subtract this amount from the account balance.
Use the class method to calculate the monthly interest.
After the last iteration, the program should display the ending balance, the total amount of deposits, the total amount of withdrawals, and the total interest earned.

I keep getting one issue in the Main Program on line 22, that if I fix, it messes up a bunch of the code. Anyone know how I could go about fixing this?

```js
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class SavingsAccountMainProgram {
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     
     System.out.print("How much money is in the account?: ");
     double startingBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();

 
     System.out.print("Enter the annual interest rate:");
     double annualInterestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

     
     SavingsAccountClass savingAccountClass = new SavingsAccountClass();
     SavingsAccount savingsAccountClass = savingAccountClass.new SavingsAccount(
             startingBalance, annualInterestRate);

     
     System.out.print("How long has the account been opened? ");
     double months = keyboard.nextInt();

     double montlyDeposit;
     double monthlyWithdrawl;
     double interestEarned = 0.0;
     double totalDeposits = 0;
     double totalWithdrawn = 0;

     
     for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++) {

         
         System.out.print("Enter amount deposited for month: " + i + ": ");
         montlyDeposit = keyboard.nextDouble();
         totalDeposits += montlyDeposit;

         
         savingsAccountClass.deposit(montlyDeposit);

        
         System.out.print("Enter amount withdrawn for " + i + ": ");
         monthlyWithdrawl = keyboard.nextDouble();
         totalWithdrawn += monthlyWithdrawl;

        
         savingsAccountClass.withdraw(monthlyWithdrawl);

        
         savingsAccountClass.addInterest();

        
         interestEarned += savingsAccountClass.getLastAmountOfInterestEarned();
     }

   
     keyboard.close();

     
     DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

     
     System.out.println("Total deposited: $" + dollar.format(totalDeposits));
     System.out.println("Total withdrawn: $" + dollar.format(totalWithdrawn));
     System.out.println("Interest earned: $" + dollar.format(interestEarned));
     System.out.println("Ending balance: $"
             + dollar.format(savingsAccountClass.getAccountBalance()));
 
}}
```

And the other program for this

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class SavingsAccountClass {
 class SavingsAccount {

     private double accountBalance;
     private double annualInterestRate;
     private double lastAmountOfInterestEarned;

     public SavingsAccount(double balance, double interestRate) {

         accountBalance = balance;
         annualInterestRate = interestRate;
         lastAmountOfInterestEarned = 0.0;
     }

     public void withdraw(double withdrawAmount) {
         accountBalance -= withdrawAmount;
     }

     public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
         accountBalance += depositAmount;
     }

     public void addInterest() {

         // Get the monthly interest rate.
         double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12;

         // Calculate the last amount of interest earned.
         lastAmountOfInterestEarned = monthlyInterestRate * accountBalance;

         // Add the interest to the balance.
         accountBalance += lastAmountOfInterestEarned;
     }

     public double getAccountBalance() {
         return accountBalance;
     }

     public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
         return annualInterestRate;
     }

     public double getLastAmountOfInterestEarned() {
         return lastAmountOfInterestEarned;
     }
 }
}
```

Also, would anyone know how I could submit a .class file like the teacher has requested?

Comment: Fixing **what**? What is in line # 22?

Comment: What is the purpose of your `inner class`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have `SavingsAccount` as inner class. For what purpose?

Here I modified what you have shared and I think it answers the problem statement well

`main` method

```
public static void main (String arg[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How much money is in the account?: ");
    double startingBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the annual interest rate:");
    double annualInterestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

    SavingsAccount savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount(startingBalance, annualInterestRate);

    System.out.print("How long has the account been opened? ");
    double months = keyboard.nextInt();

    double montlyDeposit;
    double monthlyWithdrawl;
    double interestEarned = 0.0;
    double totalDeposits = 0;
    double totalWithdrawn = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter amount deposited for month: " + i + ": ");
        montlyDeposit = keyboard.nextDouble();
        totalDeposits += montlyDeposit;

        savingsAccount.deposit(montlyDeposit);

        System.out.print("Enter amount withdrawn for " + i + ": ");
        monthlyWithdrawl = keyboard.nextDouble();
        totalWithdrawn += monthlyWithdrawl;

        savingsAccount.withdraw(monthlyWithdrawl);

        savingsAccount.addInterest();

        interestEarned += savingsAccount.getLastAmountOfInterestEarned();
    }
    keyboard.close();

    DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

    System.out.println("Total deposited: $" + dollar.format(totalDeposits));
    System.out.println("Total withdrawn: $" + dollar.format(totalWithdrawn));
    System.out.println("Interest earned: $" + dollar.format(interestEarned));
    System.out.println("Ending balance: $" + dollar.format(savingsAccount.getAccountBalance()));
}
```

and, removed `SavingsAccountClass` and made `SavingsAccount` as the top level class

```
class SavingsAccount {
    .
    .
   //everything as it is
}
```